# Data not rendering from django database to html

Tags: python, django

Data from database to html is not rendering. The static data is rendering but unfortunately the database data is not rendering no error occurs, and page is also rendering but data is not rendering from database to the page.

Html doc

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
All Tractors
{% endblock  %}

{% block content%}
<section id="all_events">
    <h1>All Tractors</h1>
    <h1>{{posts.implementation}} hi</h1>
    <br>
    <ul>
        {% for posts in post %}
            {% include "tractor/includes/singlePost.html" %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Vews.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Post, Farmer
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
# Create your views here.
def starting_page(request):
    return render(request,"tractor/index.html")

def posts(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()  
    context = {"posts":qs}
    return render(request,"tractor/all-post.html",context)
```

This is the `Models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
# Create your models here.
from .utils import unique_slug_generator

class Farmer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone =models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    email_address = models.EmailField()

    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name()


class Post(models.Model):
    tractor_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=150)
    implementation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True, null=True,blank=True)
    tractor_company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tractor_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    farmer = models.ForeignKey(
        Farmer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.implementation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
All Tractors
{% endblock  %}

{% block content%}
<section id="all_events">
    <h1>All Tractors</h1>
    <ul>
      {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{post.implementation}} hi</h1>
        <br>
        {% include "tractor/includes/singlePost.html" %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `{% for post in posts %}`

Comment: Ok but posts.implimentation is also not working

Comment: Show us your models.py

Comment: Added models.py

Comment: {{ post.implementation }} needs to be inside the for loop.